# VB.NET 'If' statement with 'Or' conditional has both sides evaluated?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Quick question, of which the quickest and easiest answer may well be to rearrange related code, but let's see...

So I have an `If` statement (a piece of code which is a part of a full working solution written in C#) rewritten using VB.NET. I am aware the VB.NET `IIf(a, b, c)` method evaluates both `b` and `a` regardless of the trueness of the first evaluation, but this *seems* to be the case in my standard construct, too:

```
If (example Is Nothing Or example.Item IsNot compare.Item) Then
    'Proceed
End If
```

Or, rather, more appropriately:

```
If (example Is Nothing Or Not example.Item = compare.Item) Then
    'Proceed
End If
```

Here, if `example` is `Nothing` (`null`) then I still get an `NullReferenceException` - is this my fault, or is it something I just have to endure at the whim of VB.NET?

Comment: In 99,9% of all cases you should use `OrElse` and `AndAlso` instead of `or` and `and`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's your "fault" in that that's how [`Or`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx) is defined, so it's the behaviour you should expect:

> In a Boolean comparison, the Or operator always evaluates both expressions, which could include making procedure calls. The OrElse Operator (Visual Basic) performs short-circuiting, which means that if expression1 is True, then expression2 is not evaluated.

But you don't have to endure it. You can use [`OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx) to get short-circuiting behaviour.

So you probably want:

```
If (example Is Nothing OrElse Not example.Item = compare.Item) Then
    'Proceed
End If
```

I can't say it *reads* terribly nicely, but it should work...

Comment: Awesome, Jon, I find the whole of VB to be verbose and ugly; hopefully this is a write-once (again) kind of thing.

Comment: It might be verbose but ugly is a matter of taste. Verbose also could mean readable, i think it's only a matter of getting used to.

Comment: @Tim Euclid's Elements is an easy read, even more so when compared to this language.

Comment: @Jeff O: Don't judge me too harshly. ;)

Comment: Jon , maybe it's a silly question , but the fact that both languages translated  to IL code -- shouldnt they both act the same ? ( the || in c# doesnt need to calc the second argument if the first one is true)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Just because they're both translated to IL doesn't mean they're translated to the *same* IL. The languages specify the behaviour of the operators differently - `OrElse` is the equivalent to `||`, whereas `Or` is closer to `|`.

Answer (score 23):

[`OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx) is the short-circuited equivalent of [`Or`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx)