# Explanation of OR operator in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Can someone please explain the below VB.Net code snippet

```
dim val1
dim val2
dim val3
dim val4
val1 = 5
val2 = 1
val3 = val1 or val2
val4 = (val3 = val1)
Console.WriteLine (val3)
Console.WriteLine (val4)
```

When val1 = 5 and val2 = 1, in the output val3 = 5 and val4 = True

But when val1 = 5 and val2 = 2, in the output val3 = 7 and val4 = False

Again when val1 = 5 and val2 = 4, in the output val3 = 5 and val4 = True

Can someone please explain how is the output 7 in the second scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.NET 'If' statement with 'Or' conditional has both sides evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723249/vb-net-if-statement-with-or-conditional-has-both-sides-evaluated)

Comment: It's because if both values are integers `Or` does a bitwise comparison - From the [VB.Net Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator): *"The Or operator also performs a bitwise comparison of identically positioned bits in two numeric expressions"*.

Comment: The VB.NET documentation for `Or` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator) says it performs a "a bitwise disjunction on two numeric expressions.".

Comment: @ADyson, Thank you for all the information provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`Or` Operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator)

> Performs a logical disjunction on two Boolean expressions or a bitwise disjunction on two numeric expressions.

Since you are using two integer values with `Or` a bitwise disjunction is happening.

**5 Or 1 = 5**

```
  | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8
  ----------------
5 | X |   | X |
1 | X |   |   |
  ================
5 | X |   | X |
```

**5 Or 2 = 7**

```
  | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8
  ----------------
5 | X |   | X |
2 |   | X |   |
  ================
7 | X | X | X |
```

**Note:** There are [more logical and bitwise operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators) on VB.NET (e.g. `And`).

Comment: @Lankymart you've linked to the VBScript documentation, not VB.NET. Although I would think the functionality of the operator is probably the same, it's best to link to the right language

Comment: @ADyson I know, the question was originally VBScript *(even though the code isn't)* I just pasted the wrong link.

Comment: @Lankymart, Thank you for all the information provided.